# Sqlite Mono upsert

Tags: c#, sqlite, mono, upsert

Following various examples from similar questions around here, I'm trying to put together an upsert using sqlite in mono.

```
string query = string.Format(@"
                    UPDATE {0} SET data=@data, protoent=@protoent, posX=@pX, posY=@pY, posZ=@pZ, ownerpubkey=@ownerpubkey WHERE key=@key;
                    INSERT INTO {0} (key, data, protoent, posX, posY, posZ, ownerpubkey) VALUES (@key, @data, @protoent, @pX, @pY, @pZ, @ownerpubkey) WHERE changes() = 0;
                    ", PersistEntityRecord.TableName);
```

For some reason I'm getting an exception because it doesn't seem to like the WHERE part of the INSERT line

```
Exception thrown: 'Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException' in Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll

Additional information: SQLite error

near "WHERE": syntax error
```

If I remove the WHERE on the INSERT line, it runs. I'm not sure why it would be not like that part.

SqliteConnection.SQLiteVersion reports Version 3.11.0 if that helps

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [INSERT statement](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) has two forms.
The WHERE clause can be used only in the form that uses a SELECT query to specify the values to be inserted:

```sql
UPDATE {0}
SET data=@data, protoent=@protoent, posX=@pX, posY=@pY, posZ=@pZ, ownerpubkey=@ownerpubkey
WHERE key=@key;

INSERT INTO {0} (key, data, protoent, posX, posY, posZ, ownerpubkey)
SELECT @key, @data, @protoent, @pX, @pY, @pZ, @ownerpubkey
WHERE changes() = 0;
```

It might be easier to do the logic in your code:

```
execute("UPDATE ...");
if (connection.Changes == 0) {
    execute("INSERT ...");
}
```